# PDO on duplicate update error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I've checked multiple PDO posts, and they all say the syntax is incorrect, but even when checking I can't seem to find it.
Here is my code:

```
 $stmt = $pDatabase->prepare('INSERT INTO Agenda (index, date, shortdesc) VALUES :values ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date=VALUES(date), shortdesc=VALUES(shortdesc)');
```

I've tried fixing it with a `;` at the end, or inserting one at a time. It errors on the prepare, so whatever `:values` is shouldnt even matter.

This is the error produced:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'index, date, shortdesc) VALUES(?, ?, ?)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date=VALUES(date)' at line 1' in /customers/f/b/e/**************/httpd.www/editagenda.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /customers/f/b/e/**************/httpd.www/editagenda.php(14): PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO Age...') #1 {main} thrown in /customers/f/b/e/**************/httpd.www/editagenda.php on line 14

where 14 is the `prepare` line.

This line works fine in DBadmin.

My table looks like this:

```
index        date          shortdesc        longdesc           boolean
10           2015-12-12    Something        copyshort          1
11           2015-11-12    Somethi2ng       copyshort2         0
```

Comment: The SQL in the error message isn't the same as the SQL you posted. There's no `VALUES(?, ?, ?)` in `$stmt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use one placeholder for multiple values like that.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> Note:
>   Parameter markers can represent a complete data literal only. Neither part of literal, nor keyword, nor identifier, nor whatever arbitrary query part can be bound using parameters. For example, you cannot bind multiple values to a single parameter in the IN() clause of an SQL statement.

Try this instead:

```
$stmt = $pDatabase->prepare('INSERT INTO Agenda (index, date, shortdesc) VALUES (:index, :date, :shortdesc) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date=VALUES(date), shortdesc=VALUES(shortdesc)');
```

(Note that you need the `(` and `)`.) Then pass three values, one for each placeholder (`:index`, `:date`, and `:shortdesc`).

P.S. Note that `index` and `date` are [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL (and most RDBMSes). You need to wrap them in backpacks, as in:

```
$stmt = $pDatabase->prepare('INSERT INTO Agenda (`index`, `date`, shortdesc) VALUES (:index, :date, :shortdesc) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date=VALUES(`date`), shortdesc=VALUES(shortdesc)');
```

Comment: So.. what if I had a variable number of values I wanted to add based on a variable (count)? would I still have to make a loop and keep adding a new (:index,:date,:desc) , (:index2,:date2:desc2) etc? This entirely defeats the purpose of using a parameter marker, might aswell insert them directly into the query, for what I'm using it for.

Comment: @JordyBrinks Exactly. You could always create a wrapper class (e.g., a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)) to automate the looping for you.

Comment: @JordyBrinks Please see my edit above; I just noticed an additional problem which is causing your original error.

Comment: Thanks man, your update totally fixed it. did a bit of a dumb loop :::  $sql .= " (:index". $i.",:date". $i.",:desc". $i."),";  to create the query, in a for loop, but it works.

Comment: @JordyBrinks Glad to help!